# Overheating problems causing Ubuntu 13.10 to power off.

Tags: wubi, overheating

I'm using Lenovo Z370 laptop and I made a dual boot with Windows 7 and Ubuntu 13.10. I noticed that since I started using Ubuntu 13.10 my laptop frequently overheats and it powers off because of the excess heat. Any explanation? Thank you so much... Noland

Comment: It may be that your fans are being blocked - try going on more smooth surfaces in cool rooms. Don't put the laptop on smothering things like duvets.

Comment: I had this problem - the fans were blocked. Does it run fine in Windows/another OS?

Answer (score 1):

**What happened:** Overheating can be caused by several factors.

1. You might be running CPU/GPU intensive programs that are very demanding on the hardware.
2. There might be poor ventilation at your workspace.
3. Worse case scenario, it might be a hardware problem that's causing this.

I took the liberty of looking up your laptop's specs, the specific model you're using does not have dedicated graphics. So that eliminates the possible cause of graphics card problems.

**What you can do:** Here's just some possible methods to solve your crisis.

1. Install TLP, it's a wonderful program for increasing your laptop's power efficiency, which in turns increases the battery life and lowers the operating temperature. Copy/paste the following lines into the terminal while you're on Ubuntu. Search up 'Terminal' in the dash or press Ctrl + Alt + T.

   `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp` (adds the ppa so you can get future updates)

   `sudo apt-get update` (gets the latest version)

   `sudo apt-get install tlp tlp-rdw smartmontools ethtool` (installs TLP)

   `sudo tlp start` (starts TLP right away after its installed)
2. Make sure your workspace is well ventilated, put your laptop over a surface that lets heat spread out faster.
3. Buy a cooling fan pad to put under your laptop.
4. If none of those worked to relive the heat problem, then its either caused by a problem with software or hardware, you should seek professional help from where you bought your laptop.

Answer (score 1):

The Best choice to reduce the power and prevent to heat you pc just install the *laptop tools* it reduce the fan speed and save battery life.

```
sudo apt-get install laptop-mode-tools
```

or Either you can use *TLP*

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tlp tlp-rdw
sudo tlp start
```

**Note : Use only one on both of them.**

hope it helps to you.

Answer (score 0):

Does your laptop have Nvidia hybrid graphics? Did you install Bumblebee? If not then that may be the cause of overheating.
Check this http://bumblebee-project.org/